# Jquery Divide Not updating Variable

Tags: jquery

My jQuery divide function is not working, it works once then no longer updates the variable. It's a bit strange as the other two numbers are updating.

Here's the code, I just can't see the error:

```
$(".inc").on("click", function() {

  // Get the price from data in the div
  var price = $('#price').data("price");

  // Grab the Quantities of each of the Multiple add Quantities
  var quant = 0;
  $('.multiple_add').each(function(i,n){
    quant += parseInt($(n).val(),10);
  });

  // Full Price
  var fullPrice = price * quant;

  // Work out the Meals
  var meals = 14 * quant;

  // Per Meal
  var permeal = fullPrice / meals;
  console.log(meals);
  console.log(fullPrice);
  console.log(permeal);
});
```

`perMeal` just doesn't update again, just sits on the same value while the other 2x values do update?

Changing either value to an integer then makes it work, but it doesn't work with 2x variables dividing

Comment: Technically, `permeal` never updates.  It's a `var` that is only set once.

Comment: How did you confirm that `fullPrice` and `meals` do update?

Comment: `console.log` at the bottom of the script.

Comment: By "bottom" are you referring to the two logs in the click handler?

Comment: Can you please share the example values. Maybe it is updating but the value is always the same like 10/5=2, 100/50=2, 50/25=2 as you see the 2 numbers are changing but the division seems not to be changing.

Comment: @Taplar Yes, the `meals` and `fullPrice` update perfectly. The `perMeal` doesn't.

Comment: not clear how that is possible....

Comment: Keep in mind the code uses 'permeal', but you keep saying 'perMeal' in your question and comments.  Variables are case sensitive.  Are you typoing your question and comments?

Comment: Most definitely price is a string and should be parsed into a number.